# monero-wallet-rpc not working for curl

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm using curl to request from the monero-wallet-rpc, but somehow it does not recognize the user/password. I used the following command

> curl -u user:password -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getbalance"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

I'm sure that the monero-wallet-rpc  running correctly since I can connect throught it by using a browser, it ask for a user/password and it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enable http digest authentication:

```
curl --digest
     -u user:password
     -X post
     -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":"0", "method":"getbalance"}'
     -H 'content-type: application/json'
     http://127.0.0.1:8082/json_rpc
```

Comment: See the `--digest` example on https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above correct answer if you use the username and password generated by the `monero-wallet-rpc` make sure to copy it correctly!

Example:

Starting `monero-wallet-rpc` with:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18083 --wallet-file "/path/to/your/walletfile" --prompt-for-password
```

generates a new `monero-wallet-rpc.18083.login` login-credential file.

When printing the `username:password` combination from `monero-wallet-rpc.18083.login` with

```
cat monero-wallet-rpc.18083.login
```

it printed something like this for me:

```
monero:uAD5d089I7VEm9sJTN9epA==%
```

The last character `%` is an escape character. The password is: `uAD5d089I7VEm9sJTN9epA==`

This curl succeeded:

```
curl --digest -u monero:uAD5d089I7VEm9sJTN9epA== -X post -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:18083/json_rpc
```

Note: tested on Mac with `Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.1-release)`